# How do I get project's PackageReferences within DiagnosticAnalyzer

Tags: roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

subj,

I need to validate that some particular attribute usage also requires particular package to be referenced directly. Thus I need to get somehow the list of PackageReferences within DiagnosticAnalyzer.

How do I do that?

Comment: for this you should use `MsBuild` to get all `PackageReferences` from your project, not the `Roslyn`

Comment: How do I get top level csproj for particular semantics? Is there any lib with object model of csproj file or any other way to add diagnostics with fix that adds PackageReference to csproj?

Comment: You can try to retrieve relevant `Document` for your `SenaticModel` or `Compilation` and then retrieve relevant `.proj` file from `Solution` or `Workspace`.

You can parse, build and analyze `.proj` file just using [MsBuild](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Build/)

Comment: If the PackageReference you want to test for contains a regular library that is referenced by your project, and you know the name of a type from that library, you could test for its presence using GetTypeByMetadataName. For example, if you want to test that you have a PackageReference to Newtonsoft.Json, you could write `bool haveReference = context.Compilation.GetTypeByMetadataName("Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert") != null;`.

Comment: @KrisVandermotten, that is the actual case I need to make sure that assembyl isn't simply referenced, but added as a PackageReference. The reason is that package containt crusial build.targets and simply referencing only dll isn't enough